# Count entries by ranges?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like so:

```js
deposits:
userId | amount
1      | 10
1      | 20
3      | 10
4      | 10
```

I need query which returns this:

```js
count | amount
2     | 10      // id 3 and 4
1     | 30       // id 1
```

Count of users with this sum of amounts(balance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to aggregate twice. The first time to SUM amount for each user. The second time to count the number of users for each amount.

```
select count(*), amount
from
(
    select userId, sum(amount) amount
    from deposits
    group by userId
) dt
group by amount
```